# Getting SSL/TLS error while scraping a secure website via C# and HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, ssl

I'm trying to write C# code to scrape html code from a secure website (i.e. https://www.exampe.com).

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with .Net Framework 4.5.2.

This is my code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

When the above code is run, the following error is raised at line #2, `GetResponse()`:

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

When I use regular HTTP URL, then the above code works fine. It only breaks on HTTPS.

PS:

1. This website is external, meaning outside of our network and works fine when I view it via any browser. I assume it's got all necessary legitimate and valid certificates.
2. And by the way, my code works fine when I run it at home on a separate computer that's not connected to my company's network.

Please help!

Comment: Is the certificate of the website valid (both in name and date) and signed by a valid CA authority that is trusted by your computer's root store?

Comment: The website I'm trying to access is not my website, it's the external client website.  The website works fine when I try viewing it via any known browser.  It's only failing when I try to access it via c#.

So back to your question, I would assume that the website has all valid certificates.

Comment: Increase logging verbosity and look at which part of the TLS handshake went wrong. Alternatively use a network sniffer but that will only give you part of the answers. PS: please use `example.com` when obfuscating names and not other imaginary names.

Comment: "The website works fine when I try viewing it via any known browser. " That does not help a lot because your Java code is certainly not using the same truststore than any browser, so if the problem is related to the certificate validation and which CA it uses, you need to make sure the truststore your java code uses has the relevant CA certificate(s). "I would assume that the website has all valid certificates." TLS does not work like you seem to think it does, the client has to validate, based on local content, the remote certificate. Among other things.

Comment: Patrick, thank you for your feedback.  I'm really new to the SSL/TLS and certificates in general.  I've never dealt with this stuff before.  I'm really not sure if I understand where you're getting.  What exactly do I need to do in order to get my C# code working?

Comment: Could be a problem with negotiating the algorithms/ciphers. Doing a packet capture (Wireshark) and examining the packets could help identify. You might also look at using [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) and comparing the algorithms on your good computer vs the bad one. You will definitelly need to do as Simon's answer suggests though: .NET 4.5.2 won't negotiate TLS 1.2 by default unless you do that. You could also consider upgrading to latest version of .NET Framework, which should negotiate correct TLS version automatically - still wouldn't resolve algorithm/cipers.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a TLS 1.2 problem. You have to tell C# to use TLS 1.2:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

add this code before your requests.

Comment: Just tried it.  I added this code, but my app still threw same error.

Answer (score -4):

I found an answer to my question.  All that needs to be done is to add the following line of code before creating a request:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

... and the rest is same as I had originally.
```

Now my app works great!

Thank you!

Comment: ....Simon suggested this very thing. So why are you posting a separate answer, and why did you tell him it didn't work? Also - you only need to run this line of code once in your application. It will stay on TLS 1.2 until your app restarts. So it makes the most sense to run it at the very beginning of your app, such as your Main method, Application_Start event etc.

Comment: The problem is, in his solution he's not explaining where to use this line of code.  I kept trying it after I created HttpWebRequest and it kept throwing error.  Then I found out on one of the forums that someone recommended putting this line of code before creating HttpWebRequest.  That's why I decided to create a separate post.

But I still appreciate his and everyone else's help.  Thank you all so much!

Comment: it says quite clearly in his answer to put it before the request

Comment: You should delete this answer, accept Simon's, and remove the comment saying it didn't work.